# multiple chained dropdown using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I want to create multiple chained dropdown in codeigniter, on the first dropdown it was working properly, but i want to select another dropdown after second combobox. How to write ajax for second dropdown so i can get the third dropdown results.

my Model

```
 function loadcaryear() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(year) FROM drv_master_car_brand");

    return $query->result();

}

function loadcarmake($year) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(make) FROM drv_master_car_brand where year = '{$year}' ");

    return $query->result();
}


function loadmodelfrombrand($make) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT model FROM drv_master_car_brand WHERE make = '{$make}'");

    return $query->result();
}
```

my Controller.

```
function carbyyear() {
    $arrCaryear = $this->modelRegister->loadcaryear();

    foreach ($arrCaryear as $caryears) {
        $arrcaryear[$caryears->year] = $caryears->year;
    }

    $data['year'] = $arrcaryear;

    $this->load->view('car',$data); 
}

function ajax_car_make() {

   if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['year'])) {

        $year = $_POST['year'];
        $arrMakes = $this->modelRegister->loadcarmake($year);

        //print_r($arrModels);
        foreach ($arrMakes as $makes) {
            $arrmakes[$makes->make] = $makes->make;
        }

        $data['make'] = $arrmakes;

        print form_dropdown('make',$arrmakes);


    } else {
        redirect('site');
    }   
}
```

my View.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $('#yearcombox select').change(function () {
                var selYear = $(this).val();
                console.log(selYear);
                $.ajax({   
                    url: "ajax_car_make", 
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: "year="+selYear, 
                    dataType: "html", 

                    success: function(data) {

                        $('#makecombox').html(data);

                    },
                })
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="mydoubts">
        <div id="yearcombox"><?php echo form_dropdown('year',$year, 'onChange="showState(this);"'); ?></div>
        <div id="makecombox"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your jquery AJAX part's **data** as

```
data: {"year":selYear},
```

Hope it will work!

Thank you!

Comment: @Amir you have to also give URL in correct way!  Such as " <?php echo base_url();?>ControllerNAme/MethodName" Thank you